# Lookup reference using PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am hoping someone is able to help. I have an excel workbook which fetches data from a table within the workbook, lets call it Table 1. In this Table 1, and ID is created and a match type.

There is a Table 2 which includes the ID as one column, and the other columns are the match types.

I am using Power Query to fetch all the data from both tables and to create a Table 3 for the required output Table 1 and 2 have a relationship with the ID columns (Column 1 in both cases).

Is anyone able to assist?

Table 1

[image: Table 1]

Table 2

[image]

Required Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Table 2:

- Right-click on the `ID` column header and select `Unpivot other columns`.

On Table 1:

- Select `Table 1` query on the left Queries pane, then select `Merge queries > As New` in the Home tab in the ribbon (on the right).
- In the pop-up, select `Table 2` in for the `Right table for merge`. Then at the top, select `ID`, then `Cat` (or whichever name it is). Then do the same for Table 2 columns, ensuring you do it in the same order. You should see a `1` and a `2` in the headers, these should match.
  [image]
- In the new Query, expand the `Table 2` column.